# Evaluate a boolean condition stored as a string

Tags: javascript, php, string, boolean-expression

I have several thousand entries in a database that were scraped from a website.  They are strings which list conditions which must be met.  For example: `"(Thing1 and Thing2) or (Thing3 and Thing4)"`

I would like a user to enter a list of conditions they have, and then check them against the database.  Due to the fact that these strings come from a trusted site, and are so close to valid boolean conditions already I'm tempted to put them in an `eval()` statement.  I could parse the string, find the conditions, check if they are true, and replace them with 1 or 0.  Then replace (and, or) with (&&, ||).  Then I would check to make sure everything at that point is one of: space, 1, 0, &, |, (, or ).  If not, log the error in some way.  If it is just those characters do:

```
eval("Boolean((1 && 0) || (0 && 0))")
```

I realize `eval()` is generally a bad idea, so I'm open to other ideas.  However, in this case I feel the security is increased if I check for just those characters before running the eval, and since the input is data scraped from a trusted site.

I'm planning on doing this in javascript, but could also do it in PHP on the server.

Comment: Are you saying the data in your database is just a string of `'1'` or `'0'` or it is the logical expression expressed as a string `'(1 and 0) or (0 and 1)'`? That part isn't clear.

Comment: They are similar to the string given at the top with "Thing1" and so on.  I can run a function on that to convert it to something like "(1 && 0) || (0 and 1)" and that is what I want to evaluate.

Comment: So basically you want to check the individual conditions, but you don't want to deal with the hassle of complicated nested conditions like (a && b) || ((c || d) && (e || f)) ? I guess using eval makes sense.

Comment: I have a string which is a nested condition.  I want evaluate that condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid eval() at all cost, you could use something like this:

```js
function evalBoolean(str) {
    while (str.length > 1) {
        str = str.replace(/0 && 0|0 && 1|1 && 0|0 \|\| 0|\(0\)/g, "0");
        str = str.replace(/1 && 1|0 \|\| 1|1 \|\| 0|1 \|\| 1|\(1\)/g, "1");
    }
    return (str == "1");
}

alert(evalBoolean("((0 && 1) || (1 && 1))"));
alert(evalBoolean("(((0 || 1) && (0 || 0)) && ((1 || 1) || 0))"));
```

If you think there could be malformed input, use this safer version which returns undefined if it can't resolve the expression.

```js
function evalBoolean(str) {
    var len;
    while (str.length > 1) {
        if (str.length == len) return; else len = str.length;
        str = str.replace(/0\s*&&\s*0|0\s*&&\s*1|1\s*&&\s*0|0\s*\|\|\s*0|\(\s*0\s*\)|\s*0\s*/g, "0");
        str = str.replace(/1\s*&&\s*1|0\s*\|\|\s*1|1\s*\|\|\s*0|1\s*\|\|\s*1|\(\s*1\s*\)|\s*1\s*/g, "1");
    }
    return (str == "1");
}

alert(evalBoolean(" (( (0|| 1)  &&(0 || 0) )&& (  (1||1) ||0))"));
alert(evalBoolean("((1 && 0) && 1 )) ( && 1"));
```